# Ejecucion de un programa cliente en segundo plano cada cierto periodo de tiempo

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito hacer un programa cliente en java  para que me envie "X" informacion a una base de datos, cada poco tiempo (1-3segundos) y este en funcionamiento en segundo plando desde que se inicie el sistema hasta que se apague. Nose como puedo hacer que se ejecuten varias lineas de codigo cada "X" tiempo sin interaccion del usuario. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices la herramienta de tareas programadas de tu Sistema Operativo, por ejemplo cron en Linux, y programes una tarea que ejecute tu programa cliente java cada minuto o más, no se si se puede cada 3 segundos. Por otro lado si necesitas que el cliente java se ejecute cada 3 segundos, entonces ponle un Thread.sleep(3000). Slds.

Comment: Gracias. Lo probare asi.!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear ese programa que tenga un cron sin tener que usar las tareas programadas de tu Sistema Operativo, yo tengo hecho una aplicación que exclusivamente sirve como cron y una vez al dia realizar una petición a una API y guarda esos datos en una base de datos.
Usa esta librería: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/